# Mac (M1 Monterey) cant open application Reactotron using dmg install

Tags: macos, installation, apple-m1, reactotron

After downloading [Reactotron (v2.17.1)](https://github.com/infinitered/reactotron/releases/download/v2.17.1/Reactotron-2.17.1.dmg), I am getting a Mac error `The application "Reactotron" can't be opened.`

[image: Reactotron cant be opened]

Answer (score 5):

I was able to get it to install and run using homebrew with:

```
brew install --cask reactotron
```

Thanks to the [Reactotron help forum](https://github.com/infinitered/reactotron/issues/1140).